# std::map initializer list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, standards

The C++ standard defines a `std::map` constructor using a `std::initializer_list`:

```
map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init, const Allocator& );
```

However, where is defined what happens if the initializer list contains duplicate keys? Is the first key choosen, or the last? For example:

```
std::map<std::string, int> my_map {
  {"a", 1}, 
  {"a", 2}
};
```

In practice, it seems it behaves like `insert()`, so that the map will now contain {a: 1}.

However, I was unable to find anything in the C++ standard regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N4296 (~C++14)

> Table 102 - Associative container requirements
>
> `X(il);`  |   Same as `X(il.begin(), il.end())`.

Then from above in the table, for the iterator ctor:

> Effects: Constructs an empty
>   container and inserts elements
>   from the range `[i, j)` into it;
>   uses `c` as a comparison object.

and

> `i` and `j` satisfy input iterator requirements and refer to elements implicitly convertible to `value_type`, `[i,j)` denotes a valid range,

Note that "and inserts elements" here is *not* marked up to indicate the `insert` function, but I suppose we may interpret it that way. Also note that `i` and `j` are **input** iterators, so must be traversed in order.

.

(It is slightly harder to find this information, because the equivalent tables all have

> `il` designates an object of type `initializer_list<value_type>`

above them, so can be found by searching for `initializer_list`, but for this table the word is split over two lines, with a hyphen at the break.)

Comment: Techinally, at least from the quoted parts, the standard doesn't seem to dictate in which order the elements would be inserted.

Comment: @user2079303 Better?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's sufficient. Certainly when the passed iterator is merely an input iterator, they must be inserted in order, but the iterator of initializer_list is a random access iterator and I don't see a rule forbidding the specialisation for different types of iterators.